# Word VBA: Converting Comments and UserName to Footnotes; need author (now in footnotes) to be bold

Tags: vba, ms-word

Converting Comments and UserName to Footnotes; need author (now in footnotes) to be bold.

I can get all the text to come in properly, I've been using strAuthor to show oComment.Author and that has been working for me.  I just can't make the author bold now that the text is in the footnotes.  It still recognises the strAuthor; I tried declaring rngAuthor as Range but can't get it to marry up with the strAuthor. I would be grateful for assistance in setting the rngAuthor.  I've been able to make all the footnote bold, but I only need the author to be bold.

I asked a similar question yesterday but I was going about it the wrong way; I asked for the last 2 words to be turned bold which I now realise would mess up footnotes which haven't been converted from Comments (thanks to Cindy for helping).

```
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oComment As Comment
Dim strAuthor As String
Dim rngAuthor As Range
Dim oFootNotes As Footnotes
Dim Ftnote As Footnote
Dim rngFootnote As Word.Range

'Document is the ActiveDocument
Set oDoc = Application.ActiveDocument

'find comment
For Each oComment In ActiveDocument.Comments

Set rngAuthor = oComment.Scope.Editors

'Comment made by "Author"
  strAuthor = oComment.Author

  'create a footnote and move comment text to footnote with rngAuthor(bold)
  oDoc.oFootNotes.Add Range:=oComment.Scope, Text:=oComment.Range.Text, Text:=oComment.Range.Editors
  rngAuthor.Font.bold = True
  ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekFootnotes
  'Delete Comment
  oComment.Delete

Next
```

When I run through the code I get 
Runtime error: 13 for `Set rngAuthor = oComment.Scope.Editors`, and Runtime error 438 for `oDoc.oFootNotes.Add Range:=oComment.Scope, Text:=oComment.Range.Text,     Text:=oComment.Range.Editors`

Comment: Debbie, take a moment to read the information in the Help about the methods you're trying to use. The `Range` parameter is the place where a footnote should be created - that can't be a Comment. And you can't use the same parameter (Text) twice in one `Add` method. Nor can a string's range "move" in the manner you're trying. What you should try is to first create the footnote with the comment text, assigning that to a Footnote object. Then get the Range of that Footnote object (like yesterday), collapse it and then assign the author's name as text to the Range. Then, you can format the range.

Comment: Also - something you were also trying to do yesterday - you can't assign one object type to another object type. An Editor cannot be assigned to a Range - they aren't the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Cindy, I'll do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the footnote range allows the range to be manipulated so that the comment can be added to a footnote and then, in declaring the comment author as a string, the author name can be applied to the footnote range as text: "rngFootnote.Text = strAuthor" and that, in turn, means the author's name can be made bold by "rngFootnote.Font.bold = True".  There is also code so that, if the author's name is shown as "surname, forename", it will be converted to "forename surname".

```
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oComment As Comment
Dim strAuthor As String
Dim strForename As String
Dim strSurname As String
Dim oFootnotes As Footnotes
Dim Ftnote As Footnote
Dim rngFootnote As Word.Range

'Document is the ActiveDocument
Set oDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
Set oFootnotes = oDoc.Footnotes

'find comment
For Each oComment In ActiveDocument.Comments

  'Comment made by "Author"
  strAuthor = oComment.Author

  'create a footnote and move comment text to footnote with Author
  oDoc.Footnotes.Add Range:=oComment.Scope, Text:=oComment.Range.Text & "  "

  'the author's name now needs to be bold (now the last two words in each footnote)
  For Each Ftnote In oFootnotes               'this adds the new footnote with the comment
    Set rngFootnote = Ftnote.Range            'this is where the comment is added

    rngFootnote.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

    If InStr(strAuthor, ",") > 0 Then       'name added
      'split surname from strUserName
      strSurname = Split(strAuthor, " ")(0)
        'delete comma
        strSurname = Trim(Left(strSurname, Len(strSurname) - 1))
      'split forename from strUserName
      strForename = Right(strAuthor, Len(strAuthor) - InStrRev(strAuthor, ","))
      strForename = Trim(Right(strForename, Len(strForename) - 1))
      strAuthor = strForename & " " & strSurname
    ElseIf InStr(strAuthor, "") > 0 Then       'name added
    End If
  Next
    rngFootnote.Text = strAuthor
    rngFootnote.Font.bold = True
  'Delete comment
  oComment.Delete
Next
```